# UITableView repeats cells how to prevent it? Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I have custom class for the cell and i have `UItableView` that shows the elements of the cell such as labels and image, also i am using parse.com as backend of the app, when ever i refresh the table, the last cell will repeats the first cell, so i have been searching to find solution to prevent the repeating cell, this is my code for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       var myCell:Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as Cell

        // Configure the cell...

       myCell.label1.text = Array1[indexPath.row]
       myCell.label2.text = Array2[indexPath.row]
       myCell.label3.text = Array3[indexPath.row]
       myCell.label4.text = Array4[indexPath.row]
       myCell.postedImage.layer.cornerRadius = myCell.postedImage.frame.size.width / 2
       myCell.postedImage.clipsToBounds = true
        //get the image from parse
     imagefiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(imageData: NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                myCell.postedImage.image = image              
                }
            }
        }            
        return myCell
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after few days working on it, i discovered where is the issue and fixed it, it wasn't from the cellForRowAtIndexPath function , it was from the code communicated with parse , i added a code to prevent the repeated cell with all the elements belongs to the cell, so therefore my code it looks like this

```
Feed.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
       //here is the fix i have done
        self.Array1.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.Array2.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.Array3.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.Array4.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.Array5.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
if error == nil {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with this code:

1) Because cells are cached, it is possible that the last cell you get back has the data configured from a previous cell. The result of that is that it will show data and image from the old cell.

This can be fixed by initializing `myCell.postedImage.image` to `nil` or to some placeholder image.

2) You are doing an asynchronous request for a cached cell. This means that by the time `` finishes, `myCell` could be reused for another row. So you are setting the image on a different cell now. This also results in confusing results like you described.

Comment: so would you please help me with this?

Comment: I have used prepare for reuse in the custom class cell and made myCell.postedImage.image = nil and the problem still there, any help would be appreciate it